# TypeError when swapping object properties with destructuring assignment

Tags: javascript, arrays, destructuring

I am trying to swap two object values in JavaScript using the `[] = []` method, but my below code fails with an error saying `"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '9' of undefined",`

```js
let dataObj={"reg_price":2, "reg_price_alt":5, "ex":9}
console.log("before: ", dataObj)
[dataObj.reg_price, dataObj.ex] = [4, 5];
console.log("after: ", dataObj)
```

Is there some syntax I'm missing? I don't understand why this simple code does not work.

Comment: I can't swap object variables using this method?

Comment: I disagree because I would like to complete this task on a single line if possible, which is why for swapping two variables it would be simple to just use the line: `[dataObj.reg_price, dataObj.ex] = [dataObj.ex, dataObj.reg_price];` which works with variables not in an object

Comment: In destructuring assignment, the targets in the array have to be simple variable references. So you can't put object property references there.

Comment: @Teemu I've tried using deconstructing syntax like `({ dataObj.reg_price, dataObj.ex } = { dataObj.reg_price: 10, dataObj.ex: 20 });` but it doesnt work

Comment: Wait, this syntax works fine. You're just missing a semicolon.

Comment: I tried with fixed parenthesis / bracket syntax but no fix: `{ dataObj.reg_price, dataObj.ex } = { dataObj.reg_price: 10, dataObj.ex: 20 };`

Comment: With complete correct syntax this method still does not work: ``` let dataObj={"reg_price":2, "reg_price_alt":5, "ex":9}
console.log("before: ", dataObj)

 [dataObj["reg_price"], dataObj["reg_price_alt"]] = [dataObj["reg_price_alt"], dataObj["reg_price"]];

console.log("after: ", dataObj)
 ```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The syntax is fine. Add a semicolon to prevent the automatic semicolon insertion from thinking you want to do `console.log(...)[...]` instead of array destructuring:

```js
let dataObj = {"reg_price":2, "reg_price_alt":5, "ex":9}
console.log("before: ", dataObj); // <-- semicolon
[dataObj.reg_price, dataObj.ex] = [4, 5]
console.log("after: ", dataObj)
```

I'd take this a step further and add semicolons after every line. Caveat emptor otherwise. Example of swapping values:

```js
const o = {a: 0, b: 1};
console.log(o);
[o.a, o.b] = [o.b, o.a];
console.log(o);
```

Comment: A semicolon who would believe that - thanks a lot